# Why laravel 5.1 returning invalid argument to foreach for any type of control loop structure

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I want to show all the signature record in form .
I tried with foreach loop and other control loops , however every time it is returning with invalid arument error.
But when I dump the array sent from controller i.e $signature it is dumping some records.

```
<?php  
    if ($sigcount > 0)
    {

        $index = 0;
        while ($index < count($signature))
        {
           $ticketid = $signature[$index]->ticketid;
           $mname = $signature[$index]->mname;
            $filetype = $signature[$index]->filetype;
            $addedby = $signature[$index]->addedby;
            $patterns = $signature[$index]->patterns;
            $patterns = explode(',', $patterns);
            $sigformat = $signature[$index]->sigformat;
            $sequence = $signature[$index]->sequence;
            $scanrule = $signature[$index]->scanrule;
            $index++;
            ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Signature : #{{$index }}</strong></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
            <table style="border-spacing: 10px;padding:5px;margin:0px auto;" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <span><i>Ticket ID :</i></span>
                <input type="text" name="ticket_id" size="7" value="{{$ticketid}}" disabled="disabled"> 
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                <span><i>M Name :</i></span>
                <input type="text" name="mname" size="60" value="{{$mname}}" disabled="disabled"> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                <span><i>File Type :</i></span>
                <input type="text" name="filetype" size="10" value="{{$filetype}}" disabled="disabled">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span><i>Added By :</i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="addedby" size="10" value="{{$addedby}}" disabled="disabled">
                </td>
                <td>
                <span><i>Sig Format :</i></span>
                <input type="text" name="sigformat" size="10" value="{{$sigformat}}" disabled="disabled">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>SigID</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Patterns</th>
                </tr>

                <?php 
                $index1 = 0;
                while($index1 < sizeof($patterns))
                {
                    $index2 = 65; ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text"  size="10" value="{{chr($index)}}" disabled="disabled">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text"  size="100" value="{{$patterns[$index1]}}" disabled="disabled">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                $index1++;
                $index2++;
            } ?>


                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <span><i>ScanRule :</i></span>
                <input type="text"  size="20" value="{{$scanrule}}" disabled="disabled">
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                <span><i>Sequence :</i></span>
                    <input name="sequence" type="checkbox" <?php if($sequence == 1)?> checked>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>

        <?php  
    }
    }
?>
```

Everytime it is showing error as invalid argument passed to the foreach loop.
What is wrong in this code.

controller code:

```html
$ticket = DB::table('tickets')->where('id',$id)->get();
        $signature = DB::table('signatures')->where('ticketid',$id)->get();
        
        return view('sig.create',['ticket'=>$ticket, 'signature'=>$signature]);
```

Comment: May i see the controller code i.e., how you get data from table ?

Comment: And what are the records dumped? And what line is returning the error?

Comment: Well considering theres only one foreach loop in the whole code the `$errors->all()` whould be returning an invalid argument. But that is fine so there would be something wong in the controller please add it to your question.

Comment: Added controller code

Comment: perhaps posting your stacktrace might help. also, i wonder, why don't you use blade's `@foreach(..)`?